# How to execute different shell commands dependent on different values from the same variable parameter on ansible?

Tags: bash, shell, ansible

Ansible newbie here:

I am currently creating an ansible playbook which intends to start, stop, and restart a vm. I need to execute different shell commands dependent on specific values from the same input parameter variable. When I try to stop the VM, i'm assuming that the playbook is stopped when it runs through Start VM task. How would I be able to fix this?

```
#Start the VM
- name: Start the VM
  shell: virsh start "{{ vmname }}"
  register: vmstate_start
  when: state == "start"

- debug:
    msg: "{{ vmstate_start.stdout  }}"

#Stop the VM
- name: Stop the VM
  shell: virsh shutdown "{{ vmname }}"
  register: vmstate_stop
  when: state == "stop"

- debug:
    msg: "{{ vmstate_stop.stdout }}"

#Restart the VM
- name: Restart the VM
  shell: virsh reboot "{{ vmname }}"
  register: vmstate_reboot
  when: state == "reboot"

- debug:
    msg: "{{ vmstate_reboot.stdout }}"
```

fatal: [111.111.1.1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/root//ansible/kvm-vm-start-stop/kvm-vm-start-top.yaml': line 65, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - debug:\n      ^ here\n"}

Comment: What does this have to do with Bash? This is a problem in your YAML, no?

Answer (score 0):

When a task is skipped, it does not mutate the `register:`-ed variable in the same way as it would if it is not skipped. Thankfully, ansible always includes whether a task was skipped or not in the `skipped` field of a registered task, or one may use the `is skipped` filter. Thus, you can either guard the expression with an if, or use the `default` filter, or just similarly skip the `debug:` task to avoid the error:

```
- name: run the debug, but conditionally display the stdout
  debug:
    msg: '{{ "NO OUTPUT DUE TO SKIP" if vmstate_start.skipped else vmstate_start.stdout }}'

- name: or you can use the "default" filter
  debug:
    msg: '{{ (vmstate_start.stdout)|default("") }}'

- name: or, skip the debug task
  debug:
    msg: vmstate_start.stdout
  when: vmstate_start is not skipped
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to include the variable in the command

```
  - name: Manage the VM
    shell: "virsh {{ state }} {{ vmname }}"
    register: vmstate_result
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ vmstate_result.stdout }}"
```

If the values of the `state` variable come from an immutable list [start, stop, reboot] it is possible to create a translation table

```
vars:
  vm_command:
    start: start
    stop: shutdown
    reboot: reboot
tasks:
  - name: Manage the VM
    shell: "virsh {{ vm_command[state] }} {{ vmname }}"
    register: vmstate_result
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ vmstate_result.stdout }}"
```

In addition to the tasks above it is possible to make the play more robust and test the `state` variable

```
vars:
  vm_commands: [start, stop, reboot]
  vm_command:
    start: start
    stop: shutdown
    reboot: reboot
tasks:
  - block:
      - name: Manage the VM
        shell: "virsh {{ vm_command[state] }} {{ vmname }}"
        register: vmstate_result
      - debug:
          msg: "{{ vmstate_result.stdout }}"
    when: state in vm_commands
  - debug:
      msg: "[ERR] unkown state: {{ state }} Valid states: {{ vm_commands }}"
    when: state not in vm_commands
```

(not tested)